# Predicting multiple columns in Keras

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, keras

In Keras I have to predict 47 columns and my query is below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model_1 = Sequential([ Dense(32, input_shape=(192,)), Activation('relu'), Dense(47), Activation('softmax'), ])

model_1.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.fit(standardized_X_train, train_y, batch_size=32, epochs=15, verbose=1, validation_data=(standardized_X_test, test_y))

classes = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=128)
```

But, when I try to predict all my columns are showing NaN as predictions. Any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to predict one variable, not 47. I don't know Keras, but it looks like you are making a MLP with 32 neurons input layer but 192 variables? And then a 47 neurons hidden layer? These numbers looks mixed up. What is the value of `standardized_X_train.shape` and `train_y.shape`?

Comment: 192 corresponds to total features. standardized_X_train.shape has 192 features. train_y.shape contains 47 columns used as response variables.

Comment: Are you trying to do classification with 47 unique class labels? It's not quite clear what your desired task is.

Comment: There might be an error here : `Sequential([ Dense(32, input_shape=(192,)), Activation('relu'), Dense(47), Activation('softmax'), ])` \n What are you trying to do? Is it a 192:32:47 network?

Comment: @StatsSorceress I have 47 columns to predict and each of the 47 columns have 13 class labels each

Comment: Okay, I would recommend adding an edit to your question to explain what these 47 columns are - it sounds like you have 47 independent response variables, that each have 13 possible outcomes. Can you discuss this a bit further? It's rare to have so many responses, so I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @StatsSorceress thanks for your response. I am trying to predict Eurovision contest. Here there are 47 countries which are rated between 0 to 12 by other countries. So each of the 47 countries have 13 classes of data.

Comment: If for each country, you're trying to predict what the rating would be from each other country, then your task is called 'multi-label classification'. If instead you're trying to predict the overall score for each country, then you're doing plain old 'multi-class classification'. I think @aneeshjoshi was on the right track: is the network supposed to be 192:32:47?